# Exception when moving nodes with jquery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, adsense

I have a little problem with my code. I'm trying to move my adsense code from one node to other and works great on all browser but crash with iexplorer.

This is the error that I have in console

> SCRIPT5009: 'Array' not defined 
>   show_ads_impl.js, Line 4 Character 29

And here is my code:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
      return this.each(function(){
          var cl = $(this).clone();
          $(cl).appendTo(selector);
          $(this).remove();
      });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#download1").moveTo("#adsRoom2");
  $("#download2").moveTo("#adsRoom1");
});
```

Regards,

Comment: What makes you think the error relates to that code?

Comment: ...and that code works: http://jsbin.com/UVEloJA/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/UVEloJA/1/edit). Although I can't imagine why you're cloning and destroying, rather than simply moving (esp. with a function called `moveTo`).

Comment: Commenting the code I don't get any error, I think is a timming problem becouse inserting directly in console when the ads are correctly loaded I don't get any error and works great.

Comment: Ok, the problem is on the method remove() that cut the adsense script on the half. Any solution to fix this?